# PHP Upload - how to return error when files are exceeding the upload_max_filesize?

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload

Why do I get an empty array instead of an error message when the upload files are **exceeding** the upload_max_filesize?

How can I get the error code number 1 like this below?

```
1 => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini',
```

I have set my upload max limit to 2MB in .htaccess:

```
php_value post_max_size 2M
php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
```

My HTML form:

```
 <form class="form-submission" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload[]" id="input-file" multiple required>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default no-gradient">Submit</button>
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Then I try to upload files larger then 2MB. The result is:

```
Array ( )
```

No error coming from PHP. How can I make sure that PHP returns an error? Is it possible?

If I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133067/how-to-display-an-error-when-the-uploaded-files-are-exceeding-post-max-size-php) in my upload.php:

```
print_r($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']);
```

I get this:

```
6564878 // what is this mean??
```

Comment: Blank array has nothing to do with Upload error. Check your code, you might have some error in code.

Comment: @Alok I have nothing else in my code except `print_r($_FILES);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is in $_FILES['userfile']['error']. You just have to check that this value is UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE to detect if the file is bigger than the max size defined in your php.ini.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `$_FILES` is empty, then how can I get `$_FILES['userfile']['error']`?